# AWS Amplify advanced tier lambda secrets

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-parameter-store

there

I have some private key in the scope of my amplify app, that lambda needs to use it to make a 3-party service call. The key is too long to be stored in standard tier parameter, it should be advanced. What I did as a temporary solution is I updated the parameter tier manually in aws console to be advanced. But it breaks when I need to create new env and want to carry over existing secrets (cli tries to create a new standard parameter and place there long value)... Is there some option to create advanced parameter via amplify cli in the first place? Or some other pattern of storing long secrets in the scope of amplify that i'm not aware of?

Comment: How long is "long"?

Comment: You get 4KB per param normally, and 8KB on enhanced.  One wonders what kind of "secret" is so long, and perhaps it is not a "secret"-like a salt- but more like something that needs to be encrypted whilst on the wire?

Comment: it is 4364 chars length, so it exceeds standard tier limit. advanced tier is ok and I'm exactly looking for a way to avoid manual converting of standard tier one to advanced